# How can I toggle the border property of an element on click, without it displacing other elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css, position, border

I'm trying to build a page where people can select the colour and capacity of a product. Only one colour/capacity can be active at a given time and when one has been selected a border needs to appear around it.

You can see in my attempt below the problem of the other elements being displaced when the border is applied.

[image: border displacing items]

I thought about giving all the elements `border: 2px solid rgba(0,0,0,0)` to resolve the displacing issue then using javascript to change the border properties on click, but I think this is probably not an elegant solution.

Here is the HTML...

```
<ul>
    <li onclick="changeName('Gold')"><div class="select-colour" id="gold"></div></li>
    <li onclick="changeName('Silver')"><div class="select-colour" id="silver"></div></li>
    <li onclick="changeName('Space Grey'); "><div class="select-colour" id="space-grey"></div></li>
</ul>
```

and the CSS...

```
ul li {
          width: 47px;
          height: 47px;
          border-radius: 12px;
          border: 2px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
          padding: 3px;
       }

.select-colour {
          width: 45px;
          height: 45px;
          border-radius: 8px;
          border: 1px solid #c2bebb;
          -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px -99px 46px -86px rgba(0,0,0,0.42);
          -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px -99px 46px -86px rgba(0,0,0,0.42);
          box-shadow: inset 0px -99px 46px -86px rgba(0,0,0,0.42);
        }

#gold {
          background-color: #f5e7dc;
      }

#silver {
          background-color: #e2e2e2;
        }

#space-grey {
          background-color: #232323;
            }
```

Does anyone have any ideas about the best way to approach this? Thanks.

Comment: What you suggested is quite a good solution imo

Comment: Honestly I would do it as you did and give a white border to it. I think the other way around you will write more code anyway..

Comment: Keep the border as white when not selected. Make it colored, once selected.

Comment: please update Javascript also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `box-sizing: border-box` to the `ul li` selector like this:

```
ul li {
      width: 47px;
      height: 47px;
      border-radius: 12px;
      border: 2px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
      padding: 3px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
   }
```

Box sizing: border-box makes the element total width/height include the border and radius.

Edit:

Two links for documentation: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp

Comment: Thanks, don't know why that didn't occur to me!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a CSS only solution using radio buttons and labels. Hope this helps.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

label {
  color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

input:checked+label {
  color: black;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

#gold+label:after {
  content: "";
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  background: gold;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 5px;
  top: 30px;
  left: 0;
}

#gold:checked+label:after, #silver:checked+label:after, #bronze:checked+label:after {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

#silver+label:after {
  content: "";
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  background: silver;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 5px;
  top: 30px;
  left: 40px;
}

#bronze+label:after {
  content: "";
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  background: sandybrown;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 5px;
  top: 30px;
  left: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container colors">
  <form name="colors">
    <input type="radio" id="gold" name="color" />
    <label for="gold">Gold</label>
    <input type="radio" id="silver" name="color" />
    <label for="silver">Silver</label>
    <input type="radio" id="bronze" name="color" />
    <label for="bronze">Bronze</label>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use 
box-sizing: border-box;
Here is the link to MDN where you can find more details
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Answer (score 0):

Simply keep the border-color: transparent if the div is not selected, and change the color of the border on selection. By the way, you may add a transition to it as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
        input[type="checkbox"]:checked  ~ #hello{
            box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px hotpink;
        }
        #hello{
            width: 50px;
            margin: 20px;
        }
</style>
```

```
<input id="check" type="checkbox">
<label id="hello" for="check">Hello</label>
```

This is what you want a hidden check box

Comment: This is what Gerard do! Takes childs ice cream :)